# How many degrees does the stem of a Canyon integrated cockpit rise?

Tags: bike-fit, stem, geometry

I am plotting a Canyon Ultimate bike on BikeCad, but I can't find how many degrees the stem rises. The stem is part of the Canyon H36 integrated cockpit. In general, manifacturers of integrated-stem cockpits don't seem to specify the degrees. Shall I assume a standard number for it?

Comment: i would just assume it's horizonal

Comment: @PaulH but the Head Tube Angle varies with the size of the frame, from 69,6° up to 73,8°. And you can pick different cockpit than the one that comes with the bike.

Comment: make it horizontal on the medium then

Comment: That would be somewhere around 18°. It sounds like a lot, I am used to stems with 6--8°.

Comment: Thomson road stems are available in 10° and 17° versions

Comment: you're right, Thomson X2 goes up to 17°

Comment: Doesn't appear the stem rises at all. Looks like a slammed stem (rising stem mounted upside down) to me.  That contour on this integrated cockpit makes sense noting racing's influence on Canyon design